# Girsanov transformation and preservation of independence

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

If we create a weak solution of an SDE using the Girsanov transformation, are the initial condition and parameters independent of the transformed Wiener process if they are independent of the original Wiener process?
[This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184748/is-independence-preserved-under-the-girsanov-transformation) is similar but more general.

---

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $X_t$ be a stochastic process which satisfies the following SDE:

$$
d X_t = f(t, X_t,\Theta)dt + dW_t,
$$

where $W_t$ is a Wiener process and $\Theta$ is a random variable. We assume $W_t$ be adapted to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ and that $\Theta$ and the initial condition of the SDE $X_0$ are $\mathcal{F}_0$-measurable and independent of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $W$.

If we define a stochastic process $M_t$ by
$$
M_t := \exp\left[-\int_0^t f(s, X_s,\Theta) \,dW_s 
-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f(s, X_s,\Theta)^2 \,ds\right]
$$
and a new measure $\tilde P(A):=\int_A M_T dP$, then the process $X_t$ also satisfies $d X_t = d\tilde W_t$ where the process $\tilde W_t := \int_0^t f(s,X_s,\Theta)\,ds + W_t$ is a Wiener process under $\tilde P$. Under the measure $\tilde P$, are $X_0$ and $\Theta$ independent of $\tilde W$?

---

I know that the $\tilde P(A)=P(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_0$ because $M_t$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$ martingale and $M_0=1$, so the measures induced by $X_0$ and $\Theta$ do not change. I believe I would be able to prove the independence if it is possible to show that 
$$
P(W^{-1}(A)|\mathcal{F}_t) = \tilde P(\tilde W^{-1}(A)|\mathcal{F}_t) \qquad\text{with prob. 1},
$$
for any set $A$ from the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the classical Wiener space. Any ideas?

Comment: Your new process is a Brownian motion (adapted process) under $\tilde{P}(A)=\mathbb{E}[1_A M_t]$, so $X_0$ and $\Theta$ are still $\mathcal{F}_0$ measurable, and $P$ and $\tilde{P}$ are still the same on $\mathcal{F}_0$ and independance still hold no? What am I missing ?

Comment: @BertrandR, the fact that $\tilde W_t$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$ under $\tilde P$ does not mean it is independent of $\mathcal{F}_0$ events. Under P, for example, $X_t$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$ and can depend on $X_0$. Is there a simple proof of independence using these facts you mentioned?

Comment: Ah ok I get it now, I just misread your question. I don't think independance holds, but that's just an intuition ...

Comment: @ Dimas : What about $f(s,X_s,\theta)=|X_s-X_0+\theta|$ ? I think this introduces in $X$ a dependence in $X_0,\theta$ at every time $s>0$ that you can't get rid off in $P(X)$, while it disappears in $\tilde{P}$ ?

Comment: I was wondering if the independence would hold for arbitrary Lipschitz continuous $f$. If it only holds for very specific $f$, like the one you suggested, then it is of no use to me. I believe that if independence does not hold, than weak solutions to SDEs using Girsanov's transformation would have very limited applications. Judging by the wide usage of the transformation I would guess that independence holds. It's only a guess, anyways.

Comment: @ Dimas : hum I think I might have misunderstood the situation my suggestion would have been more judicious if applied to the filtration generated by the process $X$ rather than the original $\mathcal{F}$. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the proposition is true, that is, any $\mathcal{F}_0$-measurable random variable is independent of $\tilde W$ under $\tilde P$, and the answer is quite simple. It was simply a matter of finding a more complete statement of the Girsanov theorem / transformation.

By [definition](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/levys-characterization-of-brownian-motion/), a Wiener process on a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{0\leq t\leq T}, P)$ has $W_t-W_s$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$ for all $0\leq s \leq t \leq T$. As $W_0=0$ is almost surely, this means that the process is independent of $\mathcal{F}_0$. More complete statements of the Girsanov transformation, like that of Ikeda and Watanabe, say that $\tilde W$ is a Wiener process on the filtered space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{0\leq t\leq T}, \tilde P)$, hence independent of $\mathcal{F}_0$.